# Sending a byte array over HTTP from Android to server-side PHP script

Tags: php, android, post, encryption, aes

I have an Android application which use AES encryption to encrypt a password.
I have a key in my app and I generate a random IV for each encryption, and I will use this IV to decrypt the password in a php file.

In the android application, the IV is a byte[] and I don't know how to send it via http request.

I think I have to encode it because the byte[] generated is not convertible in a String to send it easily but I don't know how.

I was thinking to send it with a ByteArrayEntity but I can't give a name to this POST parameter so I can't receive it from my PHP file.

If you have any idea, can you help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has nothing to do with encryption then. It's about sending a byte array across a network. Why don't you just use hexadecimal?

Comment: Also, why are you encrypting a password? That sounds questionable...

Comment: You're right, it's more sending a byte across network.

I encrypt the password to avoid sending it in clear over the network to log in from the android app.

Comment: Why don't you send a hash of the password? Most systems that encrypt passwords really ought to be hashing them. Either way, you will still have the byte array problem to solve. Why don't you convert the byte array to hexadecimal?

Comment: Hashing the password on the client side is a bad pattern.  From a protocol perspective, it makes the hash of the password in the database equivalent to the password.  Anyone cracking the database would be able to use the hashes to log in as anyone they wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use base64 encoding.  Both android and java provide mechanisms to encode and decode bae64 strings into usable formats for their respective encryption mechanisms.